# Flutter convert List String to List IconData

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I convert a `List<String>` to `List<IconData>`? I have the following  `['Icons.check', 'Icons.cancel']` which I get back from the database, and I need to convert it to `List<IconData>`.

I have tried the following:

```
final icons = List<String>.from(widget.values[0]['icons'] as List<IconData>
```

Comment: I don't see it possible to search the icon from the string since all IconData in the Icons class are static members

Comment: unless you want to do a if check manually, something like this if(list[0] == 'Icons.check') { return Icons.check;}

Comment: I just want to get back to the following [Icons.check, Icons.cancel] without the string

Answer (score 1):

Try saving the icon's **codePoint** property to the database.

```
  IconData parse(int codePoint) {
    return IconData(codePoint, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons');}
```

Use it

```
Icon(parse(0xe139)) // 0xe139 = Icons.cancel.codePoint
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
List<IconData> icons = widget.values[0]['icons'].map((String element) => element == 'Icons.check' ? Icons.check : Icons.cancel).toList();
```

Comment: that could never work, the icons are dynamic from the server I don't know which icons I will be getting back

Answer (score 0):

**1. Statically**

> Use `Map` of `String` and `IconData` like:

```
Map<String, IconData> iconsMap = {
      'Icons.check': Icons.check,
      'Icons.cancel': Icons.calendar_view_day_rounded,
   };
List<String> iconStrings = ['Icons.check', 'Icons.cancel'];
 
List<IconData> icons = iconStrings.map((iconString) => iconsMap[iconString]!).toList();

print(icons);
```

---

**2. Dynamically**

> store the `iconCode` using `codepoint` of the `Icon` and you can retrieve it by parsing it.

Example:

```
IconData icon = Icons.add;
print(icon.codePoint);  // Save this in the database
```

Then you can get your `IconData` as:

```
List<String> iconInts = ['0xe139', '0xe140'];
 
List<IconData> icons = iconInts.map((iconInt) => IconData(iconInt,fontFamily:'MaterialIcons').toList();
```